# Как правильно вывести случайные записи?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть вот такой вот простой код

```
$ids = rand(1, 500000);
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id = '$ids' ORDER BY date DESC limit 40
```

У меня выводит лишь одну случайную запись. Как мне вывести 40 случайных записей?
Знаю про rand() в mysql, но такой запрос выполняется секунд 10-15.

Answer (score 0):

Решил сам:

```
$maxx=20000;  // -- числа будут от 1 до $maxx
$maxn=40;   // -- всего $maxn чисел в массиве
$r=""; // эту строку можно удалить
$x=array();    // здесь будет массив наших чисел
$tmp=array();  // временный массив
for ($i=0; $i<$maxn; $i++) {
   do {
      $a=rand(1,$maxx);
   } while(isset($tmp[$a]));
   $tmp[$a]=1;
   $x[]=$a;
   $r.="$a,"; // эту строку можно удалить
}
unset($tmp);
$r=substr($r,0,strlen($r)-1).""; // эту строку можно удалить


$query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id in ($r) ORDER BY date DESC limit 40";
```